# Split the String xml into 2 files

Tags: android

I want to put my "help text" in an xml so I can read it fro XML and setTextView to it. I know I can use the String resource. But I was wondering if I can create another file in my resources folder and add string items to it so I can use it for my textview. I don't want my long strings of "help" to be in the same file as my string resources. 
Is this possible in android or do I need to jam all Strings of my app in one file

Thank you

Comment: You can create as many files in the `/res/values` directory as you want. They don't all need to be `strings.xml` - just create a new file called `help_strings.xml` and put what you need in there or create multiple xml files if you want to split them up. As long as each string has a unique resource id it will work.

Comment: How can I call it from the code? R.help_string.x? I I did that it is not being recognized

Comment: Just call it as you always would, R.string.x the "string" part is because your resource is of type string not because thats the name of the file

Comment: Android sees all string items as a whole. It's always R.string.XYZ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create as many files in the /res/values directory as you want. They don't all need to be strings.xml - just create a new file called help_strings.xml and put what you need in there or create multiple xml files if you want to split them up. As long as each string has a unique resource id it will work.